# What code is required to restrict specific pages to read only in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm coding a MediaWiki page and need a page to be read-only. Every other page isn't restricted and should be free to edit AND read.

Any comments and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Restict editing of certain specific page is *[in the manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_editing_of_certain_specific_pages)*.

Comment: Thank you! My head kept telling me you needed some code involving arrays etc. ahaha forgot all about "protect", thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are so many features in MW. I actually stubled upon than link when I was looking for reference of a hook I thought you would need. :)

Answer (score 0):

GolezTrol's answer worked: use protect (`action=protect`). See how to [restrict editing of certain specific pages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_editing_of_certain_specific_pages) in the manual.